# mongoimport error with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb

Trying to do a mongoimport into MongoDB Atlas service,

```
mongoimport --host replication-test-cluster.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mongodb.net:27017,replication-test-cluster.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:27017,replication-test-cluster.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl -u xxxxxx -p 'xxxxxxxxxx' --authenticationDatabase admin  --db to_replicate --collection twitter_stats --drop --file City_of_Seattle_official_Twitter_accounts_statistics.csv
```

The below error throws up

```
2017-07-26T13:04:18.317+0530    [........................] to_replicate.twitter_stats   0B/40.8KB (0.0%)
2017-07-26T13:04:18.489+0530    [........................] to_replicate.twitter_stats   0B/40.8KB (0.0%)
2017-07-26T13:04:18.489+0530    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2017-07-26T13:04:18.489+0530    imported 0 documents
```

As per the [official doc](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongoimport/#copy-the-target-cluster-host-information) of Atlas I need to use the replica set name, which I could nowhere find in the atlas console

> From the connect dialog, get the cluster host information. This
>   information is specified to mongoimport in the --host option.
>
> If the Atlas cluster is a replica set, you must also retrieve the
>   replica set name. For example:

```
myAtlasRS/atlas-host1:27017,atlas-host2:27017,atlas-host3:27017
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Actually the official documentation for [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-host) says *"You can always connect directly to a single MongoDB instance by specifying the host and port number directly."* So there is no reason why you simply cannot do that. It's "preferential" to connect using the replica set seed list, but it is not actually a "requirement". Presumably though "connection dialog" as referred to in the Atlas docs means *"where we tell you what your connection string is"*. Which would be a little different but still the same info.

Comment: Tried connecting to the primary mongoimport --host replication-test-cluster-XXXXXXXXXX.net --port 27017  -u xxxxxx -p 'xxxxxxxx' --authenticationDatabase admin  --db to_replicate --collection twitter_stats --drop --file City_of_Seattle_official_Twitter_accounts_statistics.csv which is the primary still couldn't get it to connect

Comment: Are you certain it's actually on port `27017`? Because most typical hosted instances do not actually use the default port. Too easy for attackers to scan that way.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes it is 27017

Comment: Step 2 of the procedure you quoted also describes how to find the connection string in MongoDB Atlas: "From the Clusters view, click Connect for the Atlas cluster into which you want to migrate data". The connect dialog shows your IP whitelist (which you need to update if your current IP address isn't included) as well as variations of connection strings for tools and drivers. You should make sure your IP is whitelisted and try connecting with the `mongo` shell first.

Comment: If you are still having trouble can you confirm: `mongoimport --version`, your O/S version, and the type of Atlas deployment you are trying to connect to (free tier, 3.2, or 3.4).